# How to change text box to textarea?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with WooCommerce. In a specific product page, there's a custom field to capture additional text from the buyer. The field is a textbox, which needs to be a textarea for paragraph input.

I have edited the CSS and PHP files to change the 'text' attribute to 'textarea'. However the input box does not change to textarea.

```css
.ubp_extra_field {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.ubp_extra_field label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.ubp_extra_field input[type="textarea"] {
  width: 94%;
}
```

```html
do_action('wc_ubp_box_product_after_price',$product->get_id()); if(get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'ubp_enable_box_gift_message',true)=='yes'){ $label=get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'ubp_box_message_field_label',true); $label=!empty($label) ? $label
: esc_html__('Message', 'wc-ubp'); $html='
<div class="ubp_extra_field">'; $html.='
  <label for="ubp_box_message_field">'.esc_html($label).'</label>'; $html.='
  <span class="ubp_field"><input type="textarea" name="ubp_box_message_field" id="ubp_box_message_field" value=""></span>'; $html.='
</div>'; echo $html; }
```

I expect the field to be a textarea for paragraph text input. Instead the field remains a single line textbox.

Here's the page where the field is available just above the 'Add to Cart' button:
https://www.sockaboo.com/product/sockaboo-6-pack-gift-pack/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your textarea declaration is wrong it should be like: 'textarea'.

Please refer following modified version your code:

```
    do_action('wc_ubp_box_product_after_price',$product->get_id());
if(get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'ubp_enable_box_gift_message',true)=='yes'){
    $label=get_post_meta($product->get_id(),'ubp_box_message_field_label',true);
    $label=!empty($label) ? $label : esc_html__('Message', 'wc-ubp');
    $html='<div class="ubp_extra_field">';
    $html.='<label for="ubp_box_message_field">'.esc_html($label).'</label>';
    $html.='<span class="ubp_field"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="ubp_box_message_field" id="ubp_box_message_field">This is a textarea.</textarea></span>';
    $html.='</div>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Here you can write some text to display in the textarea as the default text
</textarea>
```

Read more : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp